# How do I block a service?

Tags: command-line, systemd

I know there such commands like

```
systemctl stop [servicename] && systemctl disable [service name]
```

or  same thing with sysv.
But what I mean is how do I block commands like `enable` or start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:
Nevermind, I've already found it

```
systemctl mask [service name]
```